# Rspec's instance_double creating intermittent spec failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails

I'm getting intermittent test failures when using instance_double.

I have a file with 4 specs in it. Here is the source:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe SubmitPost do
  before(:each) do
    @post = instance_double('Post')
    allow(@post).to receive(:submitted_at=)
  end

  context 'on success' do
    before(:each) do
      allow(@post).to receive(:save).and_return(true)

      @result = SubmitPost.call(post: @post)
    end

    it 'should set the submitted_at date' do
      expect(@post).to have_received(:submitted_at=)
    end

    it 'should call save' do
      expect(@post).to have_received(:save)
    end

    it 'should return success' do
      expect(@result.success?).to eq(true)
      expect(@result.failure?).to eq(false)
    end
  end

  context 'on failure' do
    before(:each) do
      allow(@post).to receive(:save).and_return(false)

      @result = SubmitPost.call(post: @post)
    end

    it 'should return failure' do
      expect(@result.success?).to eq(false)
      expect(@result.failure?).to eq(true)
    end
  end

end
```

This is a Rails 4.1.4 application. Internally, SubmitPost sets submitted_at and calls save on the passed-in Post. My Post model looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :summary, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true
  validates :submitted_at, presence: true

  scope :chronological, -> { order('submitted_at desc') }

end
```

It's super vanilla.

When I run `rake`, `rspec`, or `bin/rspec`, I get all all four tests failing 20% - 30% of the time. The error message is always:

```
Failure/Error: allow(@post).to receive(:submitted_at=)
  Post does not implement: submitted_at=
```

If I label one of the specs with `focus: true`, that one spec will fail 100% of the time.

If I replace `instance_double` with `double`, all specs will succeed 100% of the time.

It appears that instance_double is having some difficulty inferring the methods available on the Post class. It also appears to be somewhat random and timing-based.

Has anyone run into this issue? Any ideas what might be wrong? Any sense of how to go about troubleshooting this? Naturally, inserting a debugging breakpoint causes the specs to pass 100% of the time.

Comment: I have some more data on this. The root of the issue is that the Rails environment isn't being loaded when this spec runs. If I run just this file, it always fails. I have a total of four spec files. If this file runs first, it fails. If something else runs first, it succeeds. My assumption is that the earlier run is loading the Rails environment, so this test passes. This test file is located in `spec/interactors`, so that might be contributing to the issue.

Comment: More data. I verified that app/interactors, where SubmitPost lives, is in the eager_load_paths. I also tried tagging the spec with type: :feature. The error message is unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are seeing is that ActiveRecord creates column methods dynamically. `instance_double` uses `'Post'` to look up methods to verify you are stubbing them correctly (unless the class doesn't exist yet or has not been loaded).

When a prior spec loads the model, ActiveRecord will create those dynamic methods so your spec passes as RSpec can then find the methods (with a `respond_to?` call). When run in isolation the model hasn't been previously used and so ActiveRecord will not have created the dynamic methods yet and your test fails as you're experiencing.

The workaround for this is to force ActiveRecord to load the dynamic methods when they are called in your spec:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def submitted_at=(value)
    super
  end
end
```

See the RSpec documentation for further explanation and workarounds for the problem:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/dynamic-classes

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve this problem, I opened the class in a  
`before(:context) do 
    class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
        def my_attribute_setter_or_getter
            super
        end
    end
 end` 
block in my spec and overrode the methods. But then I realised, why on Earth would I go to this trouble when I can just use MyClass.new and stub that!!!
@EricM can you just use an unpersisted post and save the hassle? i.e. `@post = Post.new`

Comment: re my above comment. I worked out why double("MyClass") is better then MyClass.new for stubbing. The latter will allow you to stub anything, so if you change the name of the method in the code which you are stubbing in the spec, it does not fail in the spec and you get a false positive. using instance_double raises a nice error. To get the same effect with MyClass.new you would also have to have a line in the spec before stubbing a method like this `expect(my_double).to respond_to('the_method_i_am_about_to_stub')`